# Fundation new project stuck on bower dependencies

Tags: git, timeout, zurb-foundation, bower, zurb-foundation-5

I want to install SASS version of ZURB Foundation.

My configuration:

- Ruby 2.1.5p273
- Nodejs 0.12.0
- Bower 1.3.12
- Windows 7 64 bit

Unfortunately I'm getting this error:

[image: error msg]

I have tried many things I could found on internet like:

- i have no proxy
- i disable my firewall
- i tried to replace https / git in --global
- i cleaned bower cache
- i opened my modem port 9418 for git and 22 for https
- uninstall / reinstall bower

Any suggestions?

Comment: wow thanks to the guy who vote down my question so helpfull....

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. If you are getting down votes try to edit and improve your question. It means that your question doesn't give satisfied clarifitaon what are you asking about. If you don't know how to improve your question read the [help](http://stackoverflow.com/help/asking). And remember: posting text error messages is always better then pictures.

Answer (score 2):

you should try downgrading your version of node. I had the same problem so downgraded to 0.10.36 as per arkkab's instructions here

[Stuck on installing dependencies with bower (foundation new)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28392450/stuck-on-installing-dependencies-with-bower-foundation-new)

I'm now using these

- node: 0.10.36
- npm: 2.5.1
- bower: 1.3.12
- ruby: ruby 2.1.5p273

and can install a new libsass or compass project

hope this helps,

J.